# Passing marker id to controller function in angular google maps info infowindow event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I'm using angular google maps to represent some information on the map.

[This](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps) is the angular google maps version I'm using.

My markup is as follows

```
<ui-gmap-google-map id="mapDiv" center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
    <ui-gmap-markers models="markers|filter:filterSite" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'">
        <ui-gmap-windows idKey="'name'" show="show" control="googlemap">
<div>
    <label ng-non-bindable class="markerToolTipLabel">{{name}}</label>
    <div class="markerActionIcons" ng-controller="infoWindowController">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open customGlyph" ng-click="glyphClick('View', 'id')"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close customGlyph" ng-click="glyphClick('Dont View', 'id')"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close customGlyph" ng-click="glyphClick('Dont View', 'id')"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The data for makers is like this

```
[{
"id": 1,
"latitude": 33.640455,
"longitude": -84.43345,
"name": "Atlanta Airport",
"category": "Airport",
"icon": "assets/images/airport_small.png"
}]
```

The info window looks like this

[image]

I need to pass the **id** of the marker to the glyphclick function.

I  tried certain things like

```
ng-click="glyphClick('View', 'id')"
ng-click="glyphClick('View', id)"
ng-click="glyphClick('View', {{id}})"
ng-click="glyphClick('View', '{{id}}')"
```

But nothing is working out.
What could be the issue. How do I resolve this?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the variable name that contains the I'd?

Comment: id is inside markers array ($scope.markers). But for ui-gmap-markers, I don't have to specify the fields independently. Like {{name}}, is inside markers